# File system has become read-only after updating to 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, fsck, fdisk, tmp

I stupidly decided to update from 14.04LTS to 14.10 and then 15.04.

Since doing that, my website has gone down and file system has become read only. I have no idea what has gone wrong, as the updates completed successfully.

This is what I have found so far:

```
    root@lew:/# service apache2 status
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2015-07-12 08:36:18 EDT; 31min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 901 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 12 08:36:18 lew.im systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Jul 12 08:36:18 lew.im apache2[901]: * Starting web server apache2
Jul 12 08:36:18 lew.im apache2[901]: mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/tmp/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX’: Read-only file system
Jul 12 08:36:18 lew.im apache2[901]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 91: /etc/init.d/apache2: cannot create : Directory nonexistent
Jul 12 08:36:18 lew.im apache2[901]: *
Jul 12 08:36:18 lew.im apache2[901]: * The apache2 configtest failed.
Jul 12 08:36:18 lew.im systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 12 08:36:18 lew.im systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jul 12 08:36:18 lew.im systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
Jul 12 08:36:18 lew.im systemd[1]: apache2.service failed.
```

then fdisk -l:

```
root@lew:/# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/vda: 20 GiB, 21476933632 bytes, 41947136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 06F7B3C9-8E13-42CD-AD52-7A02301B6F16

Device     Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/vda1   2048 41945087 41943040  20G Linux filesystem
```

and fsck /

```
root@lew:/# sudo fsck /
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve 'UUID=815063a9-c956-44a6-ab11-05e1d0bb3a58'
```

I am a beginner at all of this, but from what I have read, I need to fix something in fstab? Why has updating broken this, what could have gone wrong?

I SSH in to this server, as it is hosted in DigitalOcean.

Edit:

Blkid

```
root@lew:~# blkid
/dev/vda1: LABEL="DOROOT" UUID="18254707-08e8-494e-b456-938592928a5e" TYPE="ext4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="8c484e81-f919-4803-acc7-1447fdd81b45"
```

Mount

```
root@lew:~# mount
/dev/vda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,uid=0,gid=0,mode=0755,size=1024)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,noexec,nodev,none,name=systemd)
```

Fstab

```
root@lew:~# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/vda1 during installation
#UUID=815063a9-c956-44a6-ab11-05e1d0bb3a58 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=06F7B3C9-8E13-42CD-AD52-7A02301B6F16 /               ext4    errors=remount-rw 0       1

/swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Comment: What would more interesting is the output of `mount` and the output of `sudo blkid`. May be it's only /tmp that is read-only ?

Comment: And maybe the content of `/etc/fstab` could be interesting ( = output of `cat /etc/fstab`) to [edit] to your question.

Comment: Just got locked out after trying to access the console via the web interface, it seems to have wiped my SSH keys. Just waiting on DigitalOcean to fix it. Then I'll be able to run the commands. I know that in etc/fstab the UUID is the 815063a9 one from the fsck / output. I have edited that to be the identifier from the fdisk -l output, could that fix it? @ByteCommander

Comment: Yes, maybe. Make sure in fstab it is not selected to be mounted read-only too.

Comment: @ByteCommander okay! Still waiting on the support team to unmount the recovery ISO. How do I do that?

Comment: @solsTiCe I've edited the post with outputs of mount, blkid and fstab. I have changed the UUID in fstab to the one that appeared in fdisk, and also added 'rw' to the end, but its *still* read only! :(

Comment: No. You did it wrong. You don't want in fstab the UUID of the disk in fdisk output but the UUID in blkid output. and changing rw in errors option does not matter here.

Comment: @solsTiCe ah right! Do I need the DOROOT UUID or the primary UUID, there are two output from blkid

Comment: @LewisLebentz Hello, I've the same problem here after I upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04, I also use a server from DigitalOcean.. Could you find a solution to this?

Comment: @MHS I did! If you email support, ask them to mount the recovery ISO, mount the filesystem and the open up /etc/fstab. Changed the UUID in there to the output of blkid, save and ask DO to remove the recovery disk. Restart and you should have access again!

Comment: @LewisLebentz I've mounted the recovery ISO right now, but "blkid" gives me no output, it just gives nothing?

Comment: @MHS if you go back to the menu, have you mounted the file system? Can't remember exactly what it says, but you once you have done that you should be able to access your files, and then it should show your disk

Comment: Thanks! it works now. I hope you can post that as an answer so that people find it easily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was posted in the comments by [@Lewis Lebentz Jul 26 at 15:00](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647527/file-system-has-become-read-only-after-updating-to-15-04#comment938203_647527).

I'll paraphrase so anyone looking for the answer can find it here easily. But @Lewis should post the answer himself mark it as answered and you get due credit.

**The solution:**
Open a support ticket, ask Digital Ocean to mount the recovery ISO (It's a special ISO that only they can mount).

1. Choose 1 to mount the filesystem and the edit `/etc/fstab`.
   **Note:** Use the console and run `nano` or `vi /mnt/etc/fstab`. Alternatively you can enable SSH and networking (in the recovery
   options) to login with your terminal (see [instruction](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-recover-from-file-system-corruption-using-fsck-and-a-recovery-iso)) though I
   havn't tried that myself.
2. Changed the UUID in there to the output of blkid, save.
3. Ask DO to remove the recovery disk. Restart and you should have access again!

Comment: You don't need to use the recovery mode; `mount -rw -o remount UUID=18254707-08e8-494e-b456-938592928a5e /`, edit `/etc/fstab`, and then reboot.

Comment: mount -rw -o remount UUID=ID_RETRIEVED_FROM_BLKID worked for me! Thanks :)

Comment: In case anyone is curious, the contents of /etc/fstab prior to this change are:
```UUID=815063a9-c956-44a6-ab11-05e1d0bb3a58 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0```

Answer (score 5):

You can do as ændrük posted in comments:

```
$ mount -rw -o remount /dev/vda1 /
$ sed s/wrong_uuid/correct_uuid/ -i /etc/fstab
```

..and then boot your linux again!
Make sure you change vda1 with your device name. And in the sed command, the right uuids, of course!

Comment: This worked for me except the device was just /dev/vda - obviously you need to put in what is specific to your server.

Answer (score 3):

I found this happening to me aswell. The disk UUID in /etc/fstab couldn't be resolved.
I fixed this by first finding the UUID of the disk by running

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list
```

And copying the disk UUID for mount point `/`

I then followed @ændrük comment and remounted the disk with

```
mount -rw -o remount UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
```

I then edited /etc/fstab to change the disk UUID for the root disk.

Comment: This simple solution worked for me. After those 2 changes, I rebooted my system with `reboot`